# How to load and show image (using UIImageView) using URL in custom table view cell in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, url, uiimageview

I'm trying to load an image from a URL and display it using a UIImageView in a custom tableView cell. I'm trying to implement the following solution https://www.codingem.com/swift-load-image-from-url/ which uses a UIImageView extension.

I think the problem lies somewhere in calling the string for the `loadFrom` function in the tableView protocol function `cellForRowAt` in `ViewController.swift`.

The error I'm getting is "Cannot find "loadFrom" in scope in `ViewController.swift` where `cell.myImage.image = loadFrom(URLAddress: venues[indexPath.row].image_url)` is called.

`venues` uses the `VenueInfo` struct to create an array of venue information including names and image urls that are both formatted as strings that is fetched using an API request. `image_url` and `name` are variables in the `VenueInfo` struct.

Showing the name label (`nameLabel`) in `CustomTableViewCell` is working, but showing the UIImageView (`myImage`) isn't.

My code:

`VenueInfo.swift`

```
import Foundation

struct VenueInfo {
    var name: String?
    var image_url: String?
}
```

`ViewController.swift`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var venues: [VenueInfo] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        cell.myImage.image = loadFrom(URLAddress: venues[indexPath.row].image_url)

        cell.nameLabel.text = venues[indexPath.row].name
   }
}

extension UIImageView {
    func loadFrom(URLAddress: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: URLAddress) else {
            return
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            [weak self] in
            if let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                if let loadedImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                    self?.image = loadedImage
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`CustomTableViewCell.swift`

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet var myImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `loadFrom(URLAddress:)` is a `UIImageView` method, not a `ViewController` one. So it could be `cell.myImage.loadFrom(URLAddress: venues[indexPath.row].image_url)`

Comment: `extension UIImageView {
    func loadFrom(URLAddress: String) {`

loadFrom is an extension of UIImageView so you need to call this method using imageView

cell.myImage.LoadFrom(...)

Comment: @Larme Thank you, that makes sense. This worked!

Comment: @RintoAndrews Thank you, that makes sense. This worked!